# MYSQL Selecting EXACT word with MATCH query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select posts using MATCH to find strings that contain the exact word. Currently it selects strings that contains the word no matter what it looks like. I want it to select strings that contains the exact value as defined. the sql code currently looks like this:

```
$searchstring = "#cat";
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('$searchstring' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

How do I get it to select the strings that contains the exact value that is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch over to using `LIKE`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `content` LIKE '%{$searchstring}%'"
```

That would find only posts with *at least* that search string in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `content` LIKE '%{$searchstring}%'"
```

But the above query will search and display all the results having `$searchstring` in it.

could use :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `content` LIKE '::{$searchstring}::'"
```