# Exact word match (non-English characters)

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my Mysql db (*utf-8*). I want to get exact word matches from this table. 
My query is:

```
SELECT matched_rows FROM MY_TABLE WHERE string = 'MY_STRING'
```

Problem is when I search for '**ağaç**' (tree in English) I got all rows with **ağaç, agac, ağac, agaç**. 
what I want to get is only '**ağaç**' not the rest. I also don't want results with **something agac**.

How do I get this effect?

Comment: refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131248/mysql-selecting-exact-word-with-match-query

Comment: @abhi , i already try it but did't work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i followed @gintas answer and made some modifications. in the end this one worked for me:

> SELECT ROWS FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONVERT(`string_field_name` USING latin5) = CONVERT('MY_STRING' USING latin5)

Answer (score 0):

You should try defining collation in the query

```
SELECT matched_rows FROM MY_TABLE WHERE string = 'MY_STRING' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: thanks, but i got this eeror   `COLLATION 'latin5_turkish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email REGEXP '[[:<:]]abhi[[:>:]]'

 try this link on SO i think you didnt try this?
```

LINK: [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql)

Comment: thanks! but this gives me all strings containing my SEARCH_WORD.